# How to download multiple audio file at same time with progress bar even if app is in background in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I have an app where i need to download multiple audio file from url and also i need to have progress bar for downloaded data for every file. and downloading should continue even app enter in background state.   thanks..

Comment: Background modes check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Comment: [checkout this ready tool](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mzdownloadmanager)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSURLSession`, with a configuration received from `NSURLSessionConfiguration  backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:`.

You must them implement a delegate to handle download events, as well `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` in your app's delegate.

This is all explained in detail in the Apple documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html